# AngularJS directive - access element's dataset

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my simplified template:

```
<div>
<img ng-click="addSubPlots($event)" 
     data-status="add"
     src="abc.svg" />
</div>
```

And here is a directive that loads that template:

```
a.directive("trendChartToolbar", function ($templateRequest, $compile) {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $templateRequest('template.html').then(function (html) {
            var template = angular.element(html);
            $(elem).append(template);
            template = $compile(template)(scope);
        });                   
    }
};
```

});

My expectation was that I would be able to access template's dataset and modify the 'status' key. But when I check it the dataset is empty. I know that Angular removes 'data-' but I also dont see any 'status' anywhere. Any idea how to make something like this working? The reason I am trying this is when I click on a button I need to get button's status. Here is code I am using in the controller:

```
$scope.addSubPlots = function(event){
    console.log(event.target.dataset.status);
}
```

Please share some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: I am expecting to access it in another controller and your suggestion for a service is correct. The thing is that I am going to have a number of these templates implemented and a single service property will not work. That's why I am trying to assign a unique value to every button. So, when I click I know what was clicked.

Comment: I see. Would compiling against the rootscope help?

Comment: I am trying to have data attached to a button that I can change in the directive and read in another controller.